# On dismiss ViewConttoller UI stuck

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am working on detail page view controller where i am working on 2 different API's. When i dismiss my view controller before api load complete to my home page the UI of my home page stuck for a while.I did cancel my api request on dismiss but its not working.

Code: //within presented viewcontroller on dismiss

```
let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
   sessionManager.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks in
      dataTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
      uploadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
      downloadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
   }
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: try the dismiss in inside the closure

Comment: add UIactivictyIndicator loading until getting a complete response from API.

Answer (score 1):

there is two ways you can cancel the task.

in alamofire you need to get all task and check your task in available or not if available remove and dismiss to previous VC.for e.g

```
   Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.getAllTasks { (tasks) in
        tasks.forEach { if ($0.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString == "yourURLName") { $0.cancel() }         }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

**option 2**

check your current Task is upload or download or a data task, based on the task remove your current task before dismiss, for e.g

```
 Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks in
        dataTasks.forEach { if ($0.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString == "yourURLName") { $0.cancel() }         }
         self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

for reference I taken the answer from [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1703)

Answer (score 0):

Use following code, Alamofire cancels request to fire on the background thread so your UI update in the main thread.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (sessionDataTask, uploadData, downloadData) in
                sessionDataTask.forEach { $0.cancel() }
                uploadData.forEach { $0.cancel() }
                downloadData.forEach { $0.cancel() }
            }
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```